# Change which a-tag is highlighted depending on active page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So I have a menu with different items

```html
<div class="right-nav">
    <a href="/metrics/website/index" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="/metrics/website/pages/archives">Archives</a>
</div>
```

The `class="active"` highlights the menu item, and I was wondering how I could make this class change depending on which page I was on. So if the user visited `Archives`, then that has `class="active"`.

The class is just a simple color

```
.topnav a.active {
    /* When a-tags inside this class has been clicked - do highlight*/
    color: var(--selected-nav-page);
}
```

[image: items]

All my html code is run inside php files.

**UPDATE**

Might have found something that works, using php, what do you guys think?

Made a `php` script which checks what page I'm on, and writes active or not in my a-tags.

```php
<?php
    function active($currect_page){
        $url = str_replace(".php", "", basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); //name without .php
        if($currect_page == $url){
            echo 'active'; //class name in css
        }
    }
?>

<div class="right-nav">
    <a href="#index" class="<?php active('index'); ?> active">Home</a>
    <a href="#archives" class="<?php active('archives'); ?>">Archives</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do this with HTML and CSS alone. You need code to run in the client (i.e., JavaScript), or on the backend (e.g., PHP, ASP.NET, JavaScript [via Node or Deno or whatever], etc.).

Comment: I'm running this in php, will add the tag

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve the problem? Anything not working with the given approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I dont use the `.php` on my pages, I remove that part from the filename. Beside that I use the basename of PHP_SELF, to get the  name of the current file. If that is  equal  to the name in the menu function, then write active. Only problem here would be if I had two files with same name in different directories, and added them to the menu. Because then both would be highlighted, which is why I added `basename(getcwd())`, to get the parent directory, then also includes that the function should be called with it's parent name like `active('website/index')`

```php
<?php
function active($currect_page){
    $url = basename(getcwd())."/".str_replace(".php", "", basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    //If filename is just "name" or "name.php"
    //Also checks which directory the file is in, to avoid highlighting multiple menu items with same name
    //$currect_page == $url :: parentFolder/fileName == parentFolder/fileName (without .php here)
    if($currect_page == $url || $currect_page == basename(getcwd())."/".basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){
        echo 'active'; //class name in css
    }
}
?>

<div class="right-nav">
    <a href="/metrics/website/index" class="<?php active('website/index'); ?>">Home</a>
    <a href="/metrics/website/pages/archives" class="<?php active('pages/archives'); ?>">Archives</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Feel free to edit this answer if you have another solution (will wait to accept this one, until later)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you properly, you have two separate pages, one titled archive and the other titled Home. You want to be able to highlight the name of the page that is currently open.

I would suggest that, since you have two pages on two documents, you should be able to move the class to the other option on the site you want it to appear as such.

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
  <head>
    <style>
      .topnav a.active {
        color: (colour you pick);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="right-nav">
      <a href="/metrics/website/index" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="/metrics/website/pages/archives">Archives</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I created a `UPDATE` you can look at that one. I only have one file with the menu items in, and they redirect to different pages. Thats why i need to do the active class in  a single file and switch between the selected once.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class like so:

```
document.getElementById("<arcive_id>").class = "active";
```

Comment: I would need some kind of a a-tag listener and check if the class is added or not?

Comment: No, once you want this class to change you need to use this, when? is your choice, I think it's once the new page is selected.

Comment: But I would still need to remove the class from  the old "active" class.

Comment: Else can  you show a working example on this?

Comment: In order to remove you can do:
document.getElementById("<home_id>").class = ''
to empty string

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with pure CSS. You will have to change ether the HTML of the pages. Since we don't know if you are using something like PHP or a CMS in general the only way in plain HTML/CSS would be to add the classes by hand or write some JavaScript which adds the classes dynamically. Although I won't recommend it.

Comment: Lets do it with JS or PHP, it's up to you

Comment: Maybe  my update would  help?